What characteristics (class, feats, abilities, etc) of a character interact with magic items?
I'm looking for a complete list of 1st-party characteristics a PC can have that interact with magic items. Some possibilities are the Thief's Use Magic Device, the Artificer's Magic Item Adept, and the spell Legend Lore. Feats, proficiencies, backgrounds are all welcome.

Are you asking for a list of class features that interact with magic items so you can plan a character?

I think you already mentioned two of the best options in your question: Thief and Artificer, so I'm not sure what more to tell you, other than explaining those.

Oddly, a request for a “complete list” of things that interact with magic items is probably a better fit for this site’s format than requesting recommendations as to which are the “best.” A complete list is an objective thing, and if we restrict things to 5e (and not “5.5e”), it won’t be something that needs continuous updating, and I don’t think the list as it currently stands would be overly long. I would vote to reopen that question, anyway; can’t speak for anyone else.

Thanks for the feedback, all. @SeriousBri - In my head I was comparing this question to one where folks would specify the multiple ways one could build, say, a character who specializes in grappling. There are probably a few different ways to build a "grappler specialist", meaning someone who's going to be better at grappling than your average character. I was hoping to get framework(s) for building a character who's better at finding and using magic items than your average character.

@TreeSpawned Thanks. I suppose there's Legend Lore as well, but I'm not super familiar with all of the options in new(ish) resources like Xanathar's and Tasha's, and I was hoping there'd be addition character options by now that might help realize the goal of building someone who's focused on magic items. As I noted, Thieves and Artificers are already good at this, so to be a specialist I'd hope to put together possibilities that make one even better.

Does "interaction" for purposes of this question include a simple class-specific attunement requirement? I have in mind, e.g., the holy avenger, which does have a special interaction with level 17+ of the paladin class but can only be attuned by a paladin anyway.

@screamline I think the way you interpreted it in your answer is fine.

In order to make this answer manageable, I am limiting its scope to character traits or features that make a magic item function differently than it otherwise might. That means I am excluding from this list "interactions" that are limited to attunement requirements or that otherwise require a certain race, class, spellcasting ability, alignment, etc., for the item to function at all. For example, all of the variants of instrument of the bards require attunement by a bard, and all of the abilities they offer function the same for all bards. I am including interactions where the magic item functions differently depending on who is attuned to it.
I am also excluding character traits or features that have, at most, a self-evident mathematical interaction with a magic item. For example, a monk's Unarmored Defense lets her add her Wisdom modifier to her AC, which would necessarily interact with the Wisdom increase granted by a tome of understanding. But that interaction is purely arithmetical. Likewise, attempting to control a sphere of annihilation might require an Intelligence (Arcana) check, but whether or not a character has proficiency in the Arcana skill doesn't change the item's function per se; it only affects the math on the die roll.
Within those parameters, here are all the interactions I am able to find:

Creature type

humanoid (Iggwilv's cauldron)


Race/Species

non-dwarf (axe of the dwarvish lords, belt of dwarvenkind)


Class

bard (instrument of illusions, instrument of scribing)
cleric or paladin (talisman of pure good, talisman of ultimate evil)


Class levels

17 levels of paladin (holy avenger, Nepenthe)


Ability score

Intelligence (psi crystal)


Alignment

non-evil (book of vile darkness, soul coin)
good (figurine of wondrous power (obsidian steed))
non-lawful (rod of seven parts)


Proficiency

all simple weapons (horn of the endless maze)


Class features

Magic Item Adept/Savant/Master (attune more magic items and craft them more easily)
Pact of the Blade (bond with a magic weapon)
Spellbook (copying spells from spell scrolls)
Spellcasting Ability (imbuing a spell gem)
Turn Undead/Turn the Unholy (used with icon of Ravenloft)
Use Magic Device
Weapon Bond (bond with a weapon, which could be magical)


Faith/Piety (Akmon, Hammer of Purphoros, Dekella, Bident of Thassa, Ephixis, Bow of Nylea, Khrusor, Spear of Heliod, Mastix, Whip of Erebos)
Breath weapon (black dragon mask, blue dragon mask, green dragon mask, mask of the dragon queen, red dragon mask, white dragon mask)
Character secret


 Orc stone (grants an orc stone)


Spells

antimagic field
banishment (used on a sword of vengeance)
detect magic
holy weapon (used on a magic weapon)
identify
legend lore
Nystul's magic aura (used on a magic item)



